# Executing command from PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to configure WinRM from a PowerShell script. I am using the following code

```
$WinrmCreate= "winrm create winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS @{Hostname=""$sHostName"";CertificateThumbprint=""$CertificateThumbPrint""}"
Invoke-Expression $WinrmCreate
```

The hostname and certificate thumprint are variables above and they are validated to be coming out. Verbose output shows

```
VERBOSE: winrm create winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS @{Hostname="RSNODE1";CertificateThumbprint="6C79C8E6E88779037593E6234DCE6E1A55662F87"}
```

However, the execution of the "Invoke-Expression" give the following error

```
Invalid use of command line. Type "winrm -?
```

Interestingly if I copy/paste the output of my line to a command prompt it will create the listener without error.[image: WInrm]

Researching execution of commands I find nothing that would explain this behavior.
My only theory is that the "winrm" command is a script itself and something is misbehaving.

Comment: Your theory is correct.  It is a cmd script that kicks off a ~3900 line VB script: `@cscript //nologo "%~dpn0.vbs" %*`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hashtables e.g. `@{Hostname=...}` are interpreted by PowerShell.  If you are on V3 or higher try the `--%` simple argument parsing operator:

```
$env:Hostname = $sHostName
$env:CertThumbPrint = $CertificateThumbPrint
$WinrmCreate= "winrm create --% winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS @{Hostname=`"%HostName%`";CertificateThumbprint=`"%CertThumbPrint%`"}"
```

Comment: You gave me an "ah HA!" moment , I was down the same track. ended up using:



`$WinrmCreate= "winrm create winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS @{Hostname=""$sHostName"";CertificateThumbprint=""$CertificateThumbPrint""}"`

`$WinrmArgs = "create winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS @{Hostname=""$sHostName"";CertificateThumbprint=""$CertificateThumbPrint""}"

`Start-Process "winrm" -ArgumentList $WinrmArgs`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did for me, the certificates have the FQDN:

```
$fqdn ="CertificateSubjectName"

$certificate="CN="+$fqdn

$CertificateThumbPrint=(Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\My | Where-Object { $_.Subject -eq $certificate }).thumbprint

$WinrmCreate= 'winrm create winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS `@`{Hostname=`"`'+$fqdn+'`"`;CertificateThumbprint=`"`'+$CertificateThumbPrint+'`"`}' 

invoke-expression $WinrmCreate
```